# Python not importing correctly after upgrade to 14.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I can't import import modules from the standard library with c extensions. This happened after I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 from 12.04. I've tried reinstall python, python-dev, but its not helping. I've noticed other people with similar posts, but they all use virtualenv, whereas I am not using it all.

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:16:07) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pickle, email, json, readline, socket, turtle
>>> import ctypes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: No module named _ctypes
>>> import io
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
    import _io
ImportError: No module named _io
>>> import datetime
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named datetime
```

Comment: what does `which python` output and how did you reinstall?

Comment: `/usr/local/lib/python`


`sudo apt-get install --reinstall python`

Comment: what about `which -a python`?

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/python`
`/usr/bin/python`

Comment: Alright, that did it! I am not sure how to accept your answer since its in the comments. If you leave an answer below, I can accept it since you helped me in the comments so much.

Comment: Well, /usr/local/lib/python is where it was before, I just removed it and started using the one in /usr/bin/python. But your comments helped me figure out what to do.

Comment: good, I was going to tell you to remove it, it can get messy when you have two installs, although I do actually have that myself!

Answer (score 3):

from `which -a python` we see there are two installs of python 2 in `/usr/local/lib/python` and `/usr/bin/python/` so removing `/usr/local/lib/python` will sort the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working in virtualenv, it may have broken during upgrade.
You can repair it by simply running

```
virtualenv /PATH/TO/EXISTING/ENVIRONMENT
```

or

```
virtualenv --system-site-packages /PATH/TO/EXISTING/ENVIRONMENT
```

Answer (score 1):

For No module named _ctypes Error
You can try this:

`apt-get install libffi-dev`

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your paths are not correctly setted.

Try looking at:

```
import sys
sys.path
```

maybe the python path is not there, and then is not importing the modules.

If there is not there, add the path like a new element in the list.

```
sys.path.append(new path)
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, that `which python` returns `/usr/local/lib/python`, it looks like you have a local installation of Python which is different than your distribution's installation. Distribution packages are never installed into `/usr/local` on Ubuntu. Mixing a custom-installed Python with your distribution supplied libraries (as the `/usr/lib` paths in your errors indicate) can lead to a variety of problems.

I would recommend deleting the Python installed in `/usr/local/lib` (which is an odd place to install a binary), or removing it from your PATH, so that you can access your distribution installed Python instead.