# Ubuntu 14.04 upgrade broke all my virtualenvs

Tags: virtualenv, ubuntu-14.04

I've seen a couple of fixes for this, but none have worked for me, but I gather that its my virtualenvs that got broken.  I just upgraded to 14.04 from 12.04, and now all my pyramid applications no longer work.

When I run `../bin/pserve development.ini`, I get the following error:
`ImportError: No module named _ctypes`

When I run `../bin/python setup.py develop`, (also when I try run pshell) I get:
`ImportError: No module named _io`

I've fixed one project (each pyramid app is in a separate virtualenv) by first removing the old project folder, then reinstalling the virtualenv instance and then copying my scripts back into it.  But this is time consuming, and I have several projects.

Is there a quick fix for this?
I've seen removing [duplicates of python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24985807/python-not-importing-correctly-after-upgrade-to-14-04) and [simple reinstall of virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23176697/importerror-no-module-named-io-in-ubuntu-14-04), but removing duplicates is not a good option, and the second solution didn't work for me. But maybe I did something wrong there.

I really think that there should be a quick fix for this.  Surely reinstalling all virtualenvs cannot be the only solution?

Comment: It's your default python version that is installed which differs. On Ubuntu 12.04 it was python 2.7.3 and on Ubuntu 14.04 it is 2.7.6 , but this shouldn't break your virtualenvs.

Comment: Need help or already fixed it?

Comment: Yes Please! I never found a solution beyond just reinstalling everything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named \_io in ubuntu 14.04](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23176697/importerror-no-module-named-io-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 4):

You can simply do

```
cp /usr/bin/python2 /path/to/my-virtualenv/bin/python2
```

or

```
cp /usr/bin/python3 /path/to/my-virtualenv/bin/python3
```

(Don't need to make a new virtualenv.)

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix that works is to create a new virtualenv and copy its bin/python to the broken virtualenvs. Five simple steps:

1. `mkvirtualenv lero`
2. `cd ~/.virtualenvs`
3. `for d in */; do cp lero/bin/python $d/bin/python; done`
4. `deactivate`
5. `rmvirtualenv lero`

Comment: Thanks this helped me. Also needed: sudo easy_install -U pip and sudo easy_install -U Distribute. Then I did a pip freeze and took the version of virtualbox shown and fixed it in two places here: /usr/local/bin/virtualenv.